# Bigquery: Error running query: Query exceeded resource limits for tier 1. Tier 29 or higher required. in Redash

Tags: google-bigquery

I would like to know how to increase my billing tier for only one Bigquery query in Redash (not the whole project).

I am getting this error, while trying to refresh the query in Redash:

"Error running query: Query exceeded resource limits for tier 1. Tier 29 or higher required".

According to Bigquery's documentation there are three ways to increase this limit (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing#high-compute).  However, I am not sure which one is applicable to the queries that are written directly in the Redash's query editor. It would be great if you could provide an example.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because re:dash own support forum could handle this question better. In fact, it seems someone already posted there https://discuss.redash.io/t/how-to-increase-billing-tiers-in-redashs-query-editor-for-bigquery/264. For Stack Overflow, it would be interesting to see the query and job id in case of debugging possible.

Comment: Hi @FelipeHoffa, I looked for the job ids in BigQuery Job History, but the queries that were ran from Redash do not appear in the list. This is the screenshot: https://snag.gy/MGx1eE.jpg

Comment: what happens if you copy the query and run it in http://bigquery.cloud.google.com/?

Comment: @FelipeHoffa, I copied and ran the query in BigQuery's editor, but it did not finish it's execution.  Even that I waited for about 7 minutes (it used to finish it in 3 minutes).  These are the job ids (I ran one in batch mode and another without batch mode): adept-storm-142922:bquijob_44e519d_15840c7b3b2 and adept-storm-142922:bquijob_5a5541bf_15840c18c8a

Comment: @FelipeHoffa is there a way to change the tier from the query text? (like you can switch to Standard SQL with `#standardsql`)

Comment: not now, but that would be a nice feature request to add at https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/?hl=ca